# Integrate Dash into Flask

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I am trying to integrate a Dash app into an existing Flask program with Flask-Login. If I add `server=server` to the Dash instance every route (even ones that don't exist!!!), except the specified routes in run (ie. /home, /login), take me to the Dash app.

Example:

localhost:500/ - Takes me to Dash app

localhost:5000/home - Takes me to home route

localhost:5000/da - Takes me to Dash App

If I remove the `server=server` from the Dash instance, all the path's work as I would like, but when I pull up the dashboard at localhost:5000/test I get the error 'Error Loading Layout'.

If I add a `url_base_pathname='/base/'` to the dash instance, the routes work, but the dashboard bypasses my login.

Code Files:

**server.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__,instance_relative_config=False)

server.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
```

**run.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user
from server import server
from dashboard import app as app_1
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

server.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///login.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(server)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(server)

class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@server.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@server.route('/homepage', methods=['POST'])
def homepage():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username,password=password).first()

    if not user:
        return 'User not Found'

    else:
        login_user(user)
        return render_template('homepage.html')

@server.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return index()


@server.route('/')
@server.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@server.route('/test')
@login_required
def dashboard():    
    return redirect('/dash1')


app = DispatcherMiddleware(server, {
    '/dash1': app_1.server})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5000, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

**dashboard.py**

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from server import server

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div('Dashboard Page')
```

I would appreciate any insight on this.  I've been scouring the internet for the past 2 days and can't solve this.  Ultimately, the best solution would be if I can figure out why there is a layout error when `server=server` is removed because the entire app functions other than that.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you checked the official Tutorial [https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash]. I've been following that and it worked.  I'd guess you'll need `requests_pathname_prefix`. But then your authentication might not work.

Comment: I have tried that, but it still does not work properly with the authentication.